# Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-8.1, httpwebresponse

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 App (WINRT)**. I have created a Login page and want to post login data to server and get response.

Thanks to @Kai Brummund who gave me this following method but it uses old using **System.Net.Http**; But I want to use highly recommended **Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient**

Using the new namespace, its giving me error everywhere in this method. What changes I need to make?

```
 CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken;
        public async void ReadHeaders()
        {
            cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

            // Create the message
            string address = singletonInstance.APIServer + "MkhAdapter/rest/mkh/Login";
            var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(address));

            // Add the message body
            message.Content = new StringContent(
               LoginJsonData,
                System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            ////filter/compress
            //HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();

            // Send
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var result = await client.SendAsync(message, cancellationToken.Token);

            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Get ids from result
            var finalresult = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

Comment: what are the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to do an Http Post request, right?
You can just use WebClient:

```
        // Create the message
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(singletonInstance.APIServer + "MkhAdapter/rest/mkh/Login"));

        // Add the message body
        message.Content = new StringContent(
            "{'UserCategory': 'user','Email': User_EnteredUsername, 'Password':User_EnteredPassword}",
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        // Send
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var result = await client.SendAsync(message, cancellationToken);

        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // Get ids from result
        return (await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Comment: Well 405 points out, that your Http Endpoint does not support the request type (GET). As you were previously sending a POST request, I suggest you do that again. That's why a posted a POST request in the sample.

Comment: I used your method and it uses old using System.Net.Http; But I want to use highly recomened Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient

Comment: Depends: Windows.Web.Http is available only on Windows. System.Net.Http can ne used on Android/Wpf, etc. Both feature an almost identical Api thaugh.